# Multiple select html not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I try to implement multiple select, and it showing **[see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqRFF.png)**, but it does not work.

when i click at any bottom its not work, their are not moving ....

can any one help me .......

```js
<script language="javascript">
  $("#btnLeft").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#btnRight").click(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
    $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
});

$("#rightValues").change(function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
    $("#txtRight").val(selectedItem.text());
});
  </script>
```

```css
 SELECT, INPUT[type="text"] {
    width: 160px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
 SECTION {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow: auto;
}
 SECTION > DIV {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
}
 SECTION > DIV + DIV {
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

 <head>
  <!-- Bring to you by http://www.CSSTableGenerator.com -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" type="text/css"/> 
  <script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>

 <body>
 
  <section class="container">
    <div>
        <select id="leftValues" size="5" multiple></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
        <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="rightValues" size="4" multiple>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtRight" />
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
  
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/61/)**

Looks like your JS can't find DOM elements because it's excecuted before complet page load, so just put your code inside `ready` function :

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnLeft").click(function () {
      var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
      $("#leftValues").append(selectedItem);
    });

    $("#btnRight").click(function () {
      var selectedItem = $("#leftValues option:selected");
      $("#rightValues").append(selectedItem);
    });

    $("#rightValues").change(function () {
      var selectedItem = $("#rightValues option:selected");
      $("#txtRight").val(selectedItem.text());
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes correct. code is fine just need to add to ready function.